# want a single icon on AD user desktop on windows 2008 server r2 enterprise edition

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

i want to create a single shortcut icon on Active Directory user desktop. How do i create a shortcut that is displayed on all Active Directory users desktop?

Comment: What OS are the users on? Or is this virtualization?

Comment: I notice your post is tagged as Windows Server 2008 R2. Are you trying to desktop shortcut icon out to all your user workstations?  Or are you trying to put a shortcut on the desktop of the server?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Group Policy to push these out easily.

1. Open the GP editor console, and right-click on one of your policies and click edit.
2. Next, Navigate to User Config> Preferences> Windows Settings > Shortcuts.
3. Right-click in the blank area on the right and click New
4. Change the Location field to "Desktop" to make the icon appear there.

These types of shortcuts work best when they point at resources on a network location, rather than a local file. The local file could be missing, which would result in the shortcut not working.

You also need to make sure the Group Policy you are modifying is applied to all users as well. If it is not, then your icon won't appear for everyone.

The breakdown of all the possible settings is here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753580.aspx